# PHP Validation script

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo, mysqli

The code below is modified slightly from the code in [this previous post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/287002/sql-php-login-method).

I believe the code below could be improved and more secured but i don't know how so someone please show me how an improved sample would look like

**Validation.php**

```
<?php

session_start();

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','Bebo','Bebo');

mysqli_select_db($con, 'Bebo');

$Email = $_POST['Email'];
$Pass = $_POST['Password'];

$s = "select * from Users where Email = '$Email' && Password = '$Pass' ";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $s);

$num = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($num == 1){
    $_SESSION['Email'] = $Email;
    $Date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $update = "UPDATE Users SET Last_Login = '$Date' WHERE Users.Email = '$Email'";
    mysqli_query($con, $update);
    $UpdateLastLogin = "UPDATE Users SET Login_Times = Login_Times + 1 where Email  = '$Email'";
    mysqli_query($con, $UpdateLastLogin);
    header('location:home.php');
}else{
    header('location:login.php');
} ?>
```

Comment: Please do not edit the question, especially the code, after an answer has been posted. Changing the question may cause answer invalidation. Everyone needs to be able to see what the reviewer was referring to. [What to do after the question has been answered](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).
You can ask a follow up question to this question with updated code.

Comment: Sure so sorry!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Use bound parameters in database queries

In [the answer to your previous question by Your Common Sense](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/287017/120114) was this advice:

> in SQL, always use parameters instead of PHP variables for any database interaction

However it does not appear that parameters are used. Instead of using `mysqli_query()` one could use [`mysqli_prepare()`](https://php.net/mysqli_prepare) to get a [`mysqli_stmt`](https://www.php.net/mysqli_stmt)   for use when binding parameters with [`mysqli_stmt_bind_param()`](https://php.net/mysqli_stmt_bind_param) before calling [`mysqli_stmt_execute()`](https://php.net/mysqli_stmt_execute). Each of those manual pages have examples both with Object-oriented style and Procedural style.

YCS maintains phpdelusions.net which has [a whole guide on SQL injection](https://phpdelusions.net/sql_injection), including examples using PDO for binding parameters.

## Reduce the number of queries executed

There are two update statements executed:

> ```
> $update = "UPDATE Users SET Last_Login = '$Date' WHERE Users.Email = '$Email'";
> mysqli_query($con, $update);
> $UpdateLastLogin = "UPDATE Users SET Login_Times = Login_Times + 1 where Email  = '$Email'";
> mysqli_query($con, $UpdateLastLogin);
> ```

While the difference in speed may not be very noticeable, those could be combined into a single query:

```
$update = "UPDATE Users SET Last_Login = '$Date', Login_Times = Login_Times + 1 WHERE Users.Email = '$Email'";
```

This will reduce the amount of time needed to run the script, as well as the risk of a deadlock since the table is being updated.

## Closing tag can be omitted

The last line has a closing PHP tag.

> ```
> } ?>
> ```

From the PHP documentation for [PHP tags](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php):

> If a file contains only PHP code, it is preferable to omit the PHP closing tag at the end of the file. This prevents accidental whitespace or new lines being added after the PHP closing tag, which may cause unwanted effects because PHP will start output buffering when there is no intention from the programmer to send any output at that point in the script.
>
> [image: example from php.net]

And some style guides recommend not including it. For example - from PHP Standards Recommendations [PSR-12](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) section [**2.2 Files**](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/#22-files):

> The closing `?>` tag MUST be omitted from files containing only PHP.

It is okay to keep it if desired. It may improve readability.