# Follow up to Validation Script in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, sql-injection

So I've implemented the suggestions in [Original question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/287030/276312)
And now my code looks like this:

```
<?php
require 'init.php';

$Email = $input['Email'] = trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'Email'));
$Password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'Password');
$result = $db->execute_query("SELECT 1 FROM Users WHERE Email = ? && Password = ?", [$Email, $Password]);
    if ($result->fetch_row()) {
        $Date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $_SESSION['Email'] = $Email;
        $Update = "UPDATE Users SET Last_Login = '$Date', Login_Times = Login_Times + 1 WHERE Users.Email = '$Email'";
        $stmt = $db->execute_query($Update);
        header('location:home.php');
    }
```

Is there any more improvements i can do and most importantly is my code secure enough against SQL injections?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First query looks good.

---

> any more improvements

I don't understand why you're even asking the question.
What part of Sam's "use bound variables" answer was unclear?

We start out with `$Email` coming from the internet,
so it is "attacker controlled".
And then you filter down to the subset of address spellings
which already exist in the database.
A very charitable reviewer might assume that all such rows
match a this@that regex,
but I don't feel I can assume the rest of your code
(which INSERTs or UPDATEs) is rock solid.
So by the time we execute the second SQL statement,
I'm going to conservatively assume the
variable is *still* attacker controlled.

```
        $Update = "UPDATE Users SET Last_Login = '$Date', Login_Times = Login_Times + 1
                   WHERE Users.Email = '$Email'";
```

Now `$Date` is known to contain just `[0-9 :-]+`,
but still, why follow that old string interpolation habit?
Make it a `?` bound variable already.

And if `$Email` is attacker controlled, then interpolating
[little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327)
into the WHERE clause was definitely trouble.

Why make yourself, or a reviewer, even *begin* to think
about the injection exposure?
Just use a `?` bound variable and be done with it.

---

EDIT

Here's a simple rule you can follow. It's in line with Sam's advice.
Whenever you `execute_query( ... )`, make sure you pass in a **constant** string
followed by a list of variables used by the query. The query string will
have one `?` for each such variable. That way you avoid the habit of doing
string interpolation to construct a SQL query. As I mentioned, for something
not attacker-controlled like `$Date` it doesn't actually matter. But to have
a very simple rule you can follow all the time, just always supply variables
in that list at the end (bound vars) and never as part of the string.

> show me a sample of how i can make the $Email not attacker controlled?

Let's start with a simpler example.
Suppose we're querying someone's U.S.
[ZIP code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_Code#Early_history_and_five-digit_ZIP_Codes).
So we grab it with:

```
$zip = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'zip');
```

At this point we have a string which is completely attacker controlled.
[Mallory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alice_and_Bob#Cast_of_characters)
can set it to nearly any Unicode text he wishes, including
punctuation-laden strings which will DROP table students;

How to sanitize and validate such input?

Compare this input to the regex `"^[0-9]{5}$"`,
which demands exactly five digits.
Return an error code if no match.
Now any subsequent code can safely assume
we have only digits,
we have no punctuation,
and that there's certainly no injection danger
that would let us DROP the student table.
Casting to `(int)` and bailing if that didn't
succeed is another strategy,
though for ZIPs I caution against actually *using* the integer result,
for fear of annoying Bostonians who reside in zip code 02108.
Losing the leading zero would be Bad.

For `$Email` we could similarly use a this@that regex to verify
that no punctuation and only expected unicode runes are present.
However, I will leave that regex as an exercise to the reader,
as there are diverse opinions on what are "sensible"
characters to admit in an address.
Certainly we should admit both alphanumerics and `+` PLUS
on the left side of the `@` AT-SIGN.
And rejecting a string with more than one `@` AT-SIGN would be good.
There are multiple validation libraries.
Consider delegating the "well formed email?" decision
to one of them.

Comment: i am new to this so i have minimal knowledge and im doing it for a project so i don't have enough time to learn much about it im just trying my best :/

Comment: can you please show me a sample of how i can make the $Email not attacker controlled?

Comment: Here's a simple rule you can follow. It's in line with Sam's advice. Whenever you `execute_query( ... )`, make sure you pass in a **constant** string followed by a list of variables used by the query. The query string will have one `?` for each such variable. That way you avoid the habit of doing string interpolation to construct a SQL query. As I mentioned, for something not attacker-controlled like `$Date` it doesn't actually matter. But to have a very simple rule you can follow all the time, just _always_ supply variables in that list at the end (bound vars) and never as part of the string.

Comment: `$Update = "UPDATE Users SET Last_Login = ?, Login_Times = Login_Times + 1 WHERE Users.Email = ?";
        $stmt = $db->execute_query($Update, [$Date, $Email]); `

Comment: just to make sure i understand , like this right?

Comment: Now i understand, Sorry it took me lots of time and questions but i'm new and wanted to learn and didn't understand from the documentations well TYSM!

Comment: Yes, that `execute_query()` call is exactly right, it follows the "no injection!" rule.

Comment: thank you so much now i understand the bound variables and no injection much better

Comment: *There are multiple validation libraries. Consider delegating the "well formed email?" decision to one of them.* - be very careful about this, because some of those libraries allow things that you probably wouldn't expect. For example, the PHP `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL` allows `"'+OR+1=1--;"@example.org` and `"><script>alert(1)</script>"@example.org` as "valid" email addresses.

Comment: @Bebo. For a good example of the kind of problems that bound variables fix, see https://security.stackexchange.com/a/25710/3290.

Comment: The thing is, @Gh0stFish, those *are* valid email addresses. The rules for email addresses are *weird*. But you can save (and safely display) email addresses while still treating them as potentially hostile.

Comment: @TRiG according to the RFCs, yes. In practical terms, not really, because very few mailservers will accept them. But in either case, my point is that most developers wouldn't email validation libraries to accept those, which makes them dangerous.

Comment: @Gh0stFish i don't really understand the email library part i have 0 knowledge about this as i updated it from an answer to a question before so can you please clarify  more about the email validation libraries

Comment: @Bebo in short, even if you validate an email address with a library, it can still contain things that are dangerous if you concatenate it into a SQL query or echo it to the page. So you still need to make sure that your using bound parameters/html encodin/etc when you use that email address to be safe.

Comment: @Gh0stFish ok tysm